# How to show (wrap from leftside) file path in JLabel/JTextField?

Tags: java, swing

Problem: I have a button, that opens `JFileChooser`. Near to button I want to show the path to the selected file or folder. If I just put it in `JLabel`/`JTextfield` and text out of borders, it wrap path from the right side (like `C:/My Documents/...`, but I want (I think it gives more information) to wrap (cut?) it from the left side (for example, `.../My photos/me.jpg`.

Does there exist an easy way to do it?

Comment: *"Near to button I want to show path to selected file/folder."*  Add a tool tip (that contains the path) to the button.

Answer (score 6):

[Caret](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/caretlistener.html) can do that, for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DialogTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField text;

    public DialogTest() {
        text = new JTextField("Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test", JLabel.RIGHT);
        int textLength = text.getText().length() - 2;
        text.setCaretPosition(textLength);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, text);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 110));
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                DialogTest dialogTest = new DialogTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
label.setText( file.getName() + " Path: " + file  );
```